# NSString is not appearing properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I have the following NSString:

```
NSString* searchURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22%@%22)%0A%09%09&format=json&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&callback=",symbol];  
    NSLog(@"URL IS: %@", searchURL);
```

Looks like the %22 is not being included when it is being printed:

```
URL IS: http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select220from2ahoo.finance.quotes2here              `º≠ymbol              813020n22@20X1.000982B6P-1042009&format=json&env=http0X1.8CFB8P-1023-1.9907460.000000datatables.org-1.990746alltables.env&callback=
```

How can I make sure the %22 is included in my string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to include a "%" sign in a format string use "%%"

Just like in printf et al.

Read the full documentation of stringWithFormat to avoid other bad surprises ...

Answer (score 2):

`%` is a special character in format strings. Use `%%` to escape literal percent signs.

Answer (score 0):

% character are used in encoding space in the url formation.If you want to request any url you need to encoding that with stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
. So the % sign that are appearing are the encoded form of space.So implement accordingly by clearing this fundamental